# VB row.Cells("XX").Selected = True is not really selected

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I would like to select row during searching:
Code:

```
Private Sub TextBoxSEARCH_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBoxSEARCH.TextChanged
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells("Column1").Value = TextBoxSEARCH.Text Then
            DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
            row.Cells("Column1").Selected = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Everything works, it also !show! me right row when it finds but it's not really selected, it's not the same as you click on it. For example, I have a button that is changing backcolor for a selected row and after search, it colors the first row which is selected at the beginning.

How to change it?
Thank you.

Comment: You're selecting a cell, not a row. If you want to select a row, select a row.

Comment: Also, why would you clear the selection inside that loop? That means that the selection will not be cleared if there is no match found. Surely you want to clear the current selection no matter what, so do that.

Comment: I started with VB yesterday :-D .

Comment: OK, but that doesn't have any bearing on what I posted. With regards to where you should be clearing the selection, this is an example of why you need to determine the logic first and then write code to implement that logic. If you were doing this manually, would you wait until you found a match to clear existing selections or would you do that first, to make sure that it gets done whether a match is found or not? You would do the latter, so that's the logic that your code should implement. When you write code without knowing what it has to do, it usually won't do it.

Comment: So I added ClearSelection before If loop. But can you tell me how to properly select the row?
I thought when I got DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
for the form, it would select the row.

Comment: Good that you started with VB. :) You could consider learning C# as well, since both languages have a lot of features in common and they share the same .NET environments and libraries. Quite a few popular languages are C dialects, so learning that syntax might be beneficial anyway. Also note that all future .NET progress will be reflected in C#, but not in VB.NET, as Microsoft decided to "freeze" the VB.NET language a while back. Anyway, when using VB.NET, I would advise to *always use strict mode*. That will make your VB programs more robust and it will ease a transition to C# in the future.

Comment: I have two remarks regarding your code. First, as @jmcilhinney suggested in both a commend and an answer, you can just select the entire row. Try changing the line `row.Cells("Column1").Selected = True` into `row.Selected = True`. Second, you are breaking the `For`-loop when you find a match. That's fine if you only want to find the first occurrence. But note that you could also make your grid rows multi-selectable (by setting `DataGridView1.MultiSelect = True`). Then you could select *all* rows that contain a match. Ah yes... and put that line that clears the selection *outside the loop*. :)

Comment: @Bart Hofland Thank you for the info. Data in that column are unique (check is already done), so it's ok for me. I changed to row.Selected = True, because yes, selecting cell is my mistake in code. :-) But it still not selecting properly, info in the comments below jmcilhinney's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested and it does work the way you describe. I used this code:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim table As New DataTable

    With table.Columns
        .Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Name", GetType(String))
        .Add("DoB", GetType(Date))
    End With

    With table.Rows
        .Add(1, "Peter", #6/19/1969#)
        .Add(2, "Paul", #1/1/2000#)
        .Add(3, "Mary", #5/3/2021#)
    End With

    BindingSource1.DataSource = table
    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()

    Dim matchingRow = DataGridView1.Rows.
                                    Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).
                                    FirstOrDefault(Function(dgvr) CStr(dgvr.Cells(1).Value) = TextBox1.Text)

    If matchingRow IsNot Nothing Then
        matchingRow.Selected = True
    End If
End Sub
```

and it worked exactly as expected. If you're not seeing that then either your system is broken or you're not actually matching the text. Keep in mind that you're doing a case-sensitive equality comparison, so you must match the case as well as the letters of the text. If that's not what you want then you need a case-insensitive comparison:

```vb
FirstOrDefault(Function(dgvr) CStr(dgvr.Cells(1).Value).Equals(TextBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

EDIT:

Firstly, if the `SelectionMode` is set to `FullRowSelect` then you can select either a row:

```vb
matchingRow.Selected = True
```

or a cell:

```vb
matchingRow.Cells(1).Selected = True
```

Secondly, the case-insensitive comparison I showed will throw a `NullReferenceException` if the grid includes a data-entry row, because the cell's `Value` will be `Nothing` and so `Equals` cannot be called on it. To fix that, the comparison must be a bit more complex:

```vb
Dim matchingRow = DataGridView1.Rows.
                                Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).
                                FirstOrDefault(Function(dgvr)
                                                   Dim result = CStr(dgvr.Cells(1).Value)?.Equals(TextBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

                                                   Return result.HasValue AndAlso result.Value = True
                                               End Function)
```

Finally, the issue the question is about actually has nothing to do with selection and is actually how to make the matching row the current row, which requires that a cell in that row be made the current cell. It's up to you which cell you want to place the caret in. I would think that either the first cell or the cell the comparison was performed on, but there may be a reason to use a different cell:

```vb
If matchingRow IsNot Nothing Then
    matchingRow.Cells(1).Selected = True
    DataGridView1.CurrentCell = matchingRow.Cells(1)
End If
```

Comment: You seem to be actually selecting a row. The OP was selecting a cell and expecting the whole row to become selected.

Comment: Good that you point out the case sensitivity issue here. :)

Comment: Thank you for example. But it still does the same as mine code.
Here is a screenshot: https://i.gyazo.com/6d42fb283b6ce9362162ce9d23f243c4.png
It shows blue select on that line, but the arrow is still at the first line. So basically is still first line selected and a button which targets the selected row still changing the first line.

Comment: @BartHofland, actually, I tested both selecting a cell and selecting a row and it works the same in both cases, if `SelectionMode` is set to `FullRowSelect`. I mistakenly posted the wrong one. I'll update the answer to show that both work.

Comment: @LMRig, argh! This is a perfect example of why you need to provide ALL the relevant information when you ask a question. Nowhere in your question do you mention that arrow. The problem is that you don't know the correct terminology. That's fine; you don't know until you know. We don't know that you don't know though, and we can't tell if you don't provide all the information.

Comment: @LMRig, that arrow indicates the current row, i.e. the row containing the current cell, i.e. the cell containing the caret. That is completely unrelated to selection, which is about highlighting. There is always one and only one current row, while there can be zero, one or more selected rows. If you want the matching row to be both current and selected then you have to make it both. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ey, I'm sorry. I thought when I mention that I want to use a button to change the color of the selected row by this search that you could know :-) . But ye, I should specify. Excuses
EDIT: Ah, now I know the differences!